# .NET 6.0 API + jwt-auth | API returns "invalid_token" error

Tags: .net, authentication, jwt

I'm trying to implement jwt to my project. And it was working before i changed the code. This changes doesn't affect the authorization but somehow tokens doesn't work anymore.

When I check the token from jwt.io, it says "invalid signature". And when I try to execute a request using Swagger, responds says

```
content-length: 0
date: Fri,02 Sep 2022 10:09:12 GMT
server: Kestrel
www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token"
x-firefox-spdy: h2
```

> Secret : tx9mcA4gnbigtP7ZRECnfhk9tWsHM9ZtXqbuFYWM23D3PMdRKwh74e24swqvrTh5

API/Programs.cs

```
using System.Text;
using BlogProject.Business.MapperProfile;
using BlogProject.Business.Services.AuthenticationService;
using BlogProject.Business.Services.CommentService;
using BlogProject.Business.Services.PostService;
using BlogProject.Business.Services.TagService;
using BlogProject.Business.Services.UserService;
using BlogProject.DataAccess.Data;
using BlogProject.DataAccess.Repositories.Base;
using BlogProject.DataAccess.Repositories.Base.Interfaces;
using BlogProject.DataAccess.Repositories.Relations;
using BlogProject.DataAccess.Repositories.Relations.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var isDevelopment = builder.Environment.IsDevelopment();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddCors();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        var key = builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:IssuerSigningKey"];
        var encodedKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(encodedKey);

        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
        };
    });
builder.Services.AddScoped<IJwtAuthenticationManager, JwtAuthenticationManager>();


builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    var openApiSecurityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = "Standard Authorization header using the Bearer scheme (\"bearer {token}\")",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    };

    options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", openApiSecurityScheme);
    options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
});

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MapProfile));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<BlogProjectDbContext>(
    optionsBuilder =>
    {
        var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(connectionString);

        optionsBuilder.EnableDetailedErrors(isDevelopment);
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(isDevelopment);
    });


builder.Services.AddScoped<IPostRepository, EFPostRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICommentRepository, EFCommentRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, EFUserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITagRepository, EFTagRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, EFCategoryRepository>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IPostsEditorsRepository, EFPostsEditorsRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPostsTagsRepository, EFPostsTagsRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUsersCommentReactionsRepository, EFUsersCommentReactionsRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUsersPostReactionsRepository, EFUsersPostReactionsRepository>();


builder.Services.AddScoped<IPostService, PostService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICommentService, CommentService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITagService, TagService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITagService, TagService>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (isDevelopment)
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors(policyBuilder => policyBuilder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000"));

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Business/Services/AuthenticationService/JwtAuthenticationManager.cs

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using BlogProject.DataAccess.Repositories.Base.Interfaces;
using BlogProject.Entities.Base;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using JwtRegisteredClaimNames = Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JwtRegisteredClaimNames;

namespace BlogProject.Business.Services.AuthenticationService;

public class JwtAuthenticationManager : IJwtAuthenticationManager
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly string _jwtTokenSecret;
    private readonly string _jwtTokenSubject;

    public JwtAuthenticationManager(
        IConfiguration configuration,
        IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _jwtTokenSecret = configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:IssuerSigningKey"];
        _jwtTokenSubject = configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:Subject"];
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public async Task<string?> GetJwtTokenAsync(string username)
    {
        var user = await _userRepository.ValidateUserAsync(username);
        if(user == null) return null;

        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_jwtTokenSecret));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
        var expireTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            claims : GetClaim(user),
            expires : new DateTimeOffset(expireTime).DateTime,
            signingCredentials : credentials);

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var jwtString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        return jwtString;
    }

    private IEnumerable<Claim> GetClaim(User user)
    {
        return new Claim[] 
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, _jwtTokenSubject),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
            new Claim("Id", user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim("UserName", user.Username),
            new Claim("Email", user.Email),
            new Claim("Role", user.Role)
        };
    }
}
```

API/Controller/UserController.cs : Login

```
[HttpGet("Login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username, string password)
{
    var response = await _userService.ValidateUserAsync(username, password);

    if (response == null) return NotFound();

    var tokenResponse = await _jwtAuthenticationManager.GetJwtTokenAsync(response.UserName);

    if (tokenResponse == null) throw new Exception("Token is null");

    response.Token = tokenResponse;

     Ok(response);
}
```

Comment: *When I check the token from jwt.io, it says "invalid signature".* - that usually happens when you do not copy the secret to the input field in the right column under "VERIFY SIGNATURE". Without knowing the key, jwt.io can't verify the signature.

Comment: I already copied the secret. Nothing changes.

Comment: And you're sure that is exactly the secret that was used for signing? Can you share the token?

Comment: Here:
eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJMb2dpbiIsImp0aSI6ImUyMmFlMDE3LTQ4OGItNGFiNS05NDA4LWJkM2JkMGRhNDA5MCIsImlhdCI6IjkvMi8yMDIyIDEwOjE5OjUwIEFNIiwiSWQiOiIyIiwiVXNlck5hbWUiOiJBZG1pbiIsIkVtYWlsIjoiYWRtaW5AYWRtaW4uYWRtaW4iLCJSb2xlIjoiVXNlciIsImV4cCI6MTY2MjE4OTU5MH0.GP4yeHE5OsdnkHEIloLIeOi8DQSj_M5Ab8nYRcVqq3w

Comment: I checked the token with the secret that you show above and the signature can't be verified with that secret. So it's either the wrong secret or something in the token changed since it was signed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very embarrasing. Recently I deleted some of the packages from API. Looks like deleting "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" somehow breaks the code. But there is something I don't understand. It still says "invalid signature" at jwt.io but the token works.

And Yes I pasted the secret to the field.